# R - Computing residuals for flexsurvreg or aftreg object

Tags: r, statistics, survival

I'm estimating accelerated failure time survival models with time-varying covariates and would like to compute the deviance residuals for my estimated models.

For fixed-time covariates this is easy to achieve with `survival::survreg` and `stats::residuals`. Here's an example taken from [this webpage](https://rpubs.com/kaz_yos/aft) (the data is the `ovarian` dataset included in the `survival` package):

`survregLogLogistic <- survreg(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ ecog.ps + rx,
                              data=ovarian, dist = "loglogistic")
devRes <- residuals(survregLogLogistic, type="deviance")`

However, `survival::survreg` cannot handle time-varying covariates (see [here](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/5411_d0603a8032954b98ac187bc20ec644e6.html) for an example of how this type of data can be formatted for survival analysis in R). Because of this I need to use either `flexsurv::flexsurvreg` or `eha::aftreg`, as follows (without time-varying covariates but this is enough to reproduce the issue):

`flexsurvregLogLogistic <- flexsurvreg(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ ecog.ps + rx,
                                      data=ovarian, dist = "llogis")`

The estimation works fine but the `residuals` command does not work (looking closely at the `survival::residuals` function using `methods(residuals)` one can see that there is no sub-function for either the `flexsurv::flexsurvreg` or the `eha::aftreg` functions). This is the output of the residuals function:

> > residuals(flexsurvregLogLogistic, type="deviance")
>
> NULL

And now for `eha::aftreg`:

`aftregLogLogistic <- aftreg(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ ecog.ps + rx,
                              data=ovarian, dist = "loglogistic")`

> > residuals(aftregLogLogistic, type="deviance")
>
> NULL

How can I compute deviance (or potentially martingale) residuals from either `flexsurv::flexsurvreg` or `eha::aftreg` objects?

Comment: I have the same problem and I do not know how to solve it. So far, If you write names(aftregLogLogistic), you will see there is no 'residuals' vector. Therefore, the residuals function does not work.